# blob paralelism for Integration Runtime

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have a setup with: Data Factory, 2x Integration Runtime machines, files in Azure Blob, destination table in SQL Server.

How to control paralelism? The Integration Runtimes were almost idle, yet the "peak connections" to source are sometimes 1, sometimes 5.

Much appreciated!

Played with:
Source max concurrent connections: Auto, 2, 4, 6
Sink max concurrent connections: Auto, 2
Pipeline degree of copy paralelism: Auto, 4

Execution times are about similar regardless, around 20 minutes.

Comment: Can you please post your Self-Hosted Integration Runtime setup, and the Copy Activity configuration and output details?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is  parallelism in Azure Data Factory involves adjusting various settings to optimize the performance of your data integration pipeline.
I agree with you regarding the source & sink Max Concurent concurrent connections I have performed them in my pipeline to control parallelism.
You can also try the same at your end.

Also consider few other things like, The Integration Runtime machines actually do the data movement between the source and destination.
So there could be chances IR configuration may fail.
Check if the IR VM's  are configured correctly and if they have sufficient resources to handle the load.

Now coming to the Source and Sink Max Concurrent Connections Adjust the **"Source max concurrent connections"** and "Sink max concurrent connections"
settings based volume of your data from source and destinations.
Setting Source and Sink Max Concurrent Connections   high or  low can also impact the overall performance.
It would be great if you set  to "Auto" First and monitor the performance.
then you can try increasing the values incrementally.

[image]

[image]

Next pipeline **Degree of Copy Parallelism** The **"Pipeline degree of copy parallelism" setting** determines the number of concurrent activities that can be executed within a pipeline.
Here also Set this value to "**Auto**" initially and monitor the performance.

[image]

[image]

Also Enabling staging in Azure Data Factory can potentially help improve the performance of your data transfer pipeline.
Staging involves utilizing an intermediate storage location for temporary data storage during the data movement process.

[image]

If you find that the integration runtimes are underutilized, you can increase the parallelism to a higher value like 4.